# Problems running the program when Internet speed is low (SQL Server CE)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, delay, loading

I have a program that works with SQL Server CE database and connects to it via EF and works on data.

The problem with this is that in the main form of the program, when trying to intialize a database type and retrieve data from the bank, if the user is connected to the Internet and the user Internet speed is low, this simple operation is about 25 to 30 It takes seconds, but the same user will be able to quickly turn off the Internet if they turn off their Internet.

This code is written in the `Form Load` application:

```
var db = new Entitites();
var count = db.User.Count();
```

When I run the program in VS itself, libraries that vary with Internet speed, speed of execution are `DataAnnotation` and `System.Linq`.

I've also added this code in the **Entities** class inherited from **DbContext**

```
public Entities(string connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is most likely due to Invalid Internet Proxy configuration

This appears to occur for SQL Server Compact 4.0 on any system with an invalid proxy configuration, as a Certificate Revocation List check is run each time the engine is loaded (which happens on the first call to .Open()).

Solution: To avoid this delay, which probably affects any signed app on the system in question, you must fix the configuration or disable the check

See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

Comment: How this configuration can be disabled? (programbility) @ErikEJ

Comment: It is better to fix the invalid configuration

Comment: What is meant by invalid Internet configuration?I read the article on the site you wrote but I didn't understand what invalid Internet configuration is and where to fix it. @ErikEJ

Comment: Some info here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2623724/description-of-the-cryptography-api-proxy-detection-mechanism-when-dow

Comment: This problem can arise for any device! If this problem is not solved by programming do you think it is a problem?@ErikEJ